# Tex4ht: Non-existent graphic files in the html-output

Tags: tex4ht

Having run *htlatex* on a LaTeX file (without any configuration files), I've got a lot of references to non-existent graphic files in the html-output. Usually these non-existent graphic files come in pairs, e.g.

< img src="sample23x.png" alt="PICT" >

< img src="sample28x.png" alt="PICT" >

What causes that, and how that can be avoided?

An example (`AMS-LaTeX`):

---

```
\documentclass[12pt,reqno]{amsart}

\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document} 

$$
\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ u(x,y) \end{pmatrix} \in \Lambda \subseteq    
\mathrm{dom}(a) \cap \mathrm{dom}(b) \cap \mathrm{dom}(c)
$$

\end{document}
```

---

The grapic file for this formula is produced, but the html-file contains references for two more, which are non-existent. Once `pdfpages` is removed, everything seems to be OK.

Comment: We need full example of source code that cause this behaviour

Comment: Please see an example above.

Comment: is is caused by `pdfpages` package. do you include PDF files in your document?

Comment: Yes, I did. Now I'll do without. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blank images are caused by the `pdfpages` package, respective `eso-pic`, which is called by `pdfpages`. `eso-pic` is used for placing objects at arbitrary places on the page, it uses `picture` mode for this task. Unfortunately, the `picture` is converted  to image by `tex4ht`, even when it's empty.

There is also another problem: `\includepdf` command doesn't work. So we have two issues to fix. First one can be fixed by preventing the `eso-pic` package from loading, the second one with some patches for `pdfpages`.

Here is modified version of your TeX file:

```
\documentclass[12pt,reqno]{amsart}

\makeatletter
\ifdefined\HCode
\@nameuse{:dontusepackage}{eso-pic}
\newif\ifESO@texcoord
\newcommand\AddToShipoutPicture{\@ifstar{}{}}
\let\AddToShipoutPictureBG\AddToShipoutPicture
\let\AddToShipoutPictureFG\AddToShipoutPicture
\fi
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\makeatother
\begin{document} 

$$
\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ u(x,y) \end{pmatrix} \in \Lambda \subseteq    
\mathrm{dom}(a) \cap \mathrm{dom}(b) \cap \mathrm{dom}(c)
$$

\includepdf[pages={1,2,3}]{pdfsample.pdf}    
\includegraphics[page=1]{pdfsample.pdf}

\end{document}
```

The important code is:

```
\ifdefined\HCode
\@nameuse{:dontusepackage}{eso-pic}
\newif\ifESO@texcoord
\newcommand\AddToShipoutPicture{\@ifstar{}{}}
\let\AddToShipoutPictureBG\AddToShipoutPicture
\let\AddToShipoutPictureFG\AddToShipoutPicture
\fi
```

It prevents `eso-pic` from loading and some basic macros used by `pdfpages` are defined. For `pdfpages` configuration, we can create `pdfpages.4ht` configuration file:

```
\let\pdf@page\relax
\define@key{Gin}{page}[]{\edef\pdf@page{\the\numexpr #1-1\relax}}


\def\AM@findfile#1{%
  \AM@findfile@i{#1}{pdf}%
  \AM@findfile@ii{#1}%
}
\catcode`\:=12
\renewcommand\AM@output[1]{%
  \@for\@pages:=\AM@pagestemp\do{\includegraphics[page=\@pages]{\AM@currentdocname}}
}
\catcode`\:=11

\AtBeginDocument{
  \Configure{graphics*}  
  {pdf}  
  {
    \ifx\pdf@page\relax\def\pdf@page{0}\fi
    \def\current@pdf@file{\Gin@base.pdf[\pdf@page]}    
    \def\current@png@file{\Gin@base-\pdf@page.png}%
      \expandafter\Needs\expandafter{"convert \current@pdf@file\space %\csname Gin@base\endcsname.pdf  
        \current@png@file"}%  
        \Picture[pict]{\current@png@file}%  
        \special{t4ht+@File: \csname current@png@file\endcsname}
    \let\pdf@page\relax
}  
}
\Hinput{pdfpages} 
\endinput
```

In this file, first of all we declare `page` option for `\includegraphics` command, because it isn't defined in the `DVI` mode:

```
\let\pdf@page\relax
\define@key{Gin}{page}[]{\edef\pdf@page{\the\numexpr #1-1\relax}}
```

We then can request inclusion of particular pages:

```
\renewcommand\AM@output[1]{%
  \@for\@pages:=\AM@pagestemp\do{\includegraphics[page=\@pages]{\AM@currentdocname}}
}
```

`\@for` is internal LaTeX command which can be used for looping over comma separated lists. In this case we loop over `\AM@pagestemp`, where requested pages are stored.

Finally, we need to add support for PDF images for `tex4ht`:

```
\AtBeginDocument{
  \Configure{graphics*}  
  {pdf}  
  {
    \ifx\pdf@page\relax\def\pdf@page{0}\fi
    \def\current@pdf@file{\Gin@base.pdf[\pdf@page]}    
    \def\current@png@file{\Gin@base-\pdf@page.png}%
      \expandafter\Needs\expandafter{"convert \current@pdf@file\space %\csname Gin@base\endcsname.pdf  
        \current@png@file"}%  
        \Picture[pict]{\current@png@file}%  
        \special{t4ht+@File: \csname current@png@file\endcsname}
    \let\pdf@page\relax
}  
}
```

`\pdf@page` contains the requested page, this macro is stored by `\includegraphics` `page` option. We can convert particular pdf page using Imagemagick's `convert` command in the form:

```
 convert filename.pdf[page number] filename.png
```

The converted image is then included using `\Picture` command. `\special` is used to register the output file in `tex4ht`, so it can be copied to the destination directory, for example.

Comment: Michal, you are thorough as always. Thank you very much indeed.

Comment: @Olod you are welcome. I will add support for PDF page inclusion to tex4ht  itself soon